# Store multiple values in a session

Tags: php, mysql, session

Im new in PHP. I am creating a webstore. I want to pass the values from the products in the cart to a session. the value of the session will be displayed in checkout page. please help me. heres the code.

```
$i = 0;
        $sum = 0;
        foreach($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_product){
            $product_id = $each_product['productID'];
            $sql=mysql_query("select * from tblproduct where prod_id='$product_id'");
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                $prodNo = $row["prod_no"];
                $prodID = $row["prod_id"];
                $prodName = $row["prod_name"];
                $prodPrice = $row["prod_price"];
                $prodQuan = $row["prod_quan"];
                $supp = $row["supplier"];
                $sum +=$row['prod_price'];
                $pricetotal=$prodPrice*$each_product['quantity'];
                $productname=array();
                $productname[] = $prodName;
                $_SESSION['name'] = $productname;

            }
```

Comment: sorry. there are no errors. the only problem is it only rewrites the last value from $productname[] when i am adding new values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the initialization of `$productname` out of the loop. And you only need to assign to the session variable when the loop is done.

```
        $productname=array();            
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            $prodNo = $row["prod_no"];
            $prodID = $row["prod_id"];
            $prodName = $row["prod_name"];
            $prodPrice = $row["prod_price"];
            $prodQuan = $row["prod_quan"];
            $supp = $row["supplier"];
            $sum +=$row['prod_price'];
            $pricetotal=$prodPrice*$each_product['quantity'];
            $productname[] = $prodName;
        }
        $_SESSION['name'] = $productname;
```

All the other variables like `$prodNo` and `$prodID` are being overwritten each time through the loop, so when the loop is done they'll just contain the values from the last row. I'm not sure why you're setting them, unless there's you have code in the loop that uses them that you didn't show.